# variadic template function and glBufferData

Tags: opengl, c++11, variadic-functions

I am missing something.  I've successfully setup my UBO buffer.  After memcpy'ing data into the buffer everything works without a hitch.  To clean up the code I am trying to create a function that will do the memcpy'ing and buffering.  My function looks like the following:

```
void bufferUBOData(const GLuint uboIndex)
{
    auto uboSize = sizeRegistry.find(uboIndex)->second;
    auto buffer = bufferRegistry.find(uboIndex)->second;
    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, uboSize, buffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void bufferUBOData(const GLuint uboIndex, T data, Args... args)
{
    auto buffer = bufferRegistry.find(uboIndex)->second;
    auto size = std::get<1>(dataRegistry.find(uboIndex)->second);
    auto offset = std::get<2>(dataRegistry.find(uboIndex)->second);
    auto type = std::get<3>(dataRegistry.find(uboIndex)->second);
    const int index = sizeof...(args);

memcpy(buffer + offset[index], &data, size[index] * TypeSize(type[index]));
    bufferUBOData(uboIndex, args...);   
}
```

To implement the code i've done the following.

```
//memcpy(buffer + offset[Scale], &scale, size[Scale] * TypeSize(type[Scale]));
//memcpy(buffer + offset[Translation], &translation, size[Translation] * TypeSize(type[Translation]));
//memcpy(buffer + offset[Rotation], &rotation, size[Rotation] * TypeSize(type[Rotation]));
//memcpy(buffer + offset[Enabled], &enabled, size[Enabled] * TypeSize(type[Enabled]));

//glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, uboSize, buffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
bufferUBOData(uboIndex, enabled, rotation, translation, scale);
```

Everything compiles. In the above code section if I un-comment the memcpy and glBufferData calls and comment out the bufferUBOData call everything works.  However the example as shown renders a blank screen (no geometry).

Note: When I use the bufferUBOData function I place the args in reverse order.

*Edit: removed useless while loop --> Thanks DyP for the tip on sizeof...()*

Comment: `while` could be `if`.  Its a revamped example of some variadic function code.  If sizeof... is always guaranteed to be positive or zero then the line really isn't needed +1 for that.  But that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried passing your data by reference instead of by value?

Comment: What is `offset`? As far as I can see, you'd have to provide the variadic arguments in a certain order. This might be error-prone.

Comment: @Brochu I have tried to pass data by reference and only got errors.

Comment: @Dyp if I get the simple example working then I can work to make it more robust, but at this point I am not having luck with the simple example.

Comment: @DyP the offset is the offset into the UBO buffer.

Comment: It is very hard to find an error in an code snippet without seeing the rest of it. I don't see anything obviously wrong with it; the differences two the original non-recursive `memcpy`-version are the order of `memcpy` calls (enabled will be copied first) and the acquisition of data through the two registries. Maybe it's an indexing issue with the `sizeof...` and those arrays (or whatever `offset` etc. are).

Comment: It ended up being as simple as an index miss match.  The enum values in offset[xxx] are not in order of declaration.  Doh.  I fixed that and it worked locally at least.  When I moved the function call from the body of one method to the main file I got a linker error.  But at least I solved my mystery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being that

```
bufferUBOData(uboIndex, enabled, rotation, translation, scale);
```

was not in the correct order.  It should have been.

```
bufferUBOData(uboIndex, enabled, rotation, scale, translation);
```

A detail I missed using the enum for offset[xxx].